# Solve by Completing the square

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$x^2 + x + 1 = (x^2 + x + 1/4) + 1 - 1/4 = (x + 1/2)^2 + 3/4$

I am confused as to how to get from the first step to the second. Can someone please explain this algebraically? Thank you in advance!

Comment: $x^2+x+1 = x^2+x+1 + (\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}) = (x^2+x+\frac{1}{4})+(1-\frac{1}{4})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's begin by looking at the expansion of the square of $x+b$, where $b$ is some constant.

$$(x+b)^2 = (x+b)(x+b) = x(x+b) + b(x+b) = x^2 + bx + bx + b^2 = x^2 + 2bx + b^2.$$

Now, if I removed the $b^2$ at the end, and instead we just had the expression

$$x^2 + 2bx,$$

what is the number I have to add to this expression to make it a perfect square?  Obviously, I have to add $b^2$.

Now suppose instead of $2b$ as the coefficient of $x$, suppose it is

$$x^2 + kx.$$

What is the number I need to add to make this a perfect square?  Naturally, if $k = 2b$, then we'd add $b^2$.  Equivalently, $b = k/2$, so the number we have to add is $(k/2)^2$:

$$x^2 + kx + (k/2)^2 = (x + k/2)^2.$$

This is the principle behind completing the square.

Now let's practice:  how to complete the square for

$$x^2 + 6x = 3?$$

We have to add $(6/2)^2 = 9$ to both sides:

$$x^2 + 6x + 9 = 12.$$  Then the LHS factors and we have $$(x+3)^2 = 12.$$

How about $$x^2 + 8x + 1 = 7?$$  We need $(8/2)^2 = 16$, but we already have a $1$, so we can add $15$ to both sides:

$$x^2 + 8x + 1 + 15 = 7 + 15,$$ and this becomes

$$(x+4)^2 = 22.$$

Now let's try your expression:

$$x^2 + x + 1.$$

Note that $(1/2)^2 = 1/4$, so what we need is $1/4$ but we already have $1$, so we "borrow" $1/4$ from it to get

$$x^2 + x + 1 = x^2 + x + 1/4 + 3/4 = (x + 1/2)^2 + 3/4.$$

The way this process was written in your question is a little different; instead we do an "add and subtract" trick, also known as "adding zero":

$$x^2 + x + 1 = x^2 + x + 1/4 - 1/4 + 1 = (x + 1/2)^2 + (-1/4 + 1) = (x + 1/2)^2 + 3/4.$$

It's the same thing.

Now you practice:  Complete the square for the following expressions:

$$x^2 + 7x - 10$$
$$x^2 - 4x + 8$$
$$x^2 - 5x$$
$$x^2 + x/3 + 1$$
$$x^2 - 2x + 1$$